# What does 'high temple' mean?

Tags: meaning

The following is an excerpt from a travel guide transcript about New York City. I can guess the meaning of **high temple** in the passage, but I am not sure I know what it means literally and figuratively. I looked it up in a number of dictionaries, but I failed.

> New York has always been the gateway to the Land of the Free. But it
>   is also the city of the spree — the shopping spree. The city is
>   shopaholic heaven. And Fifth Avenue with its eye-popping window
>   displays, is the **high temple** of the retail world.
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtCMtC50gwY

Answer (score 3):

Temple is not restricted to gods and idols. It also means something else! Straight from the [Oxford Dictionaries, definition 1.5](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/temple)

> - A place devoted to or seen as the centre of a particular activity or interest.

Undoubtedly, the Fifth Avenue at the Big Apple is the center of retails! Ah, I wish to shop there! :)

Answer (score 1):

A temple is a building devoted to worship of a god or gods. The high temple is the most important temple in the land.  Fifth Avenue is where the figurative god of shopping is worshipped.

> temple 1 NOUN 1A building devoted to the worship of a god or gods.

[Temple (Oxford Dictionary)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/temple)

Comment: I know you say "figurative" in your answer, but I'm still not so sure this would be the most helpful answer for learners. There is a pretty marked usage difference between the Temple in Jerusalem and the "temple" on Fifth Avenue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sentence while I was looking for a sunglasses. It goes "An oval-shaped face works with any style of Classic frame.....just stick with the high temples"
I just guessed that high temple means shop which sells some fine goods (with high price tag)